# How to integrate the following integral problem

Tags: integration

I want to evaluate the following indefinite integral that includes a derivative of Dirac Delta function.

$$e^{bx}\dfrac{d}{dx}{\delta(x-a)}$$

In Mathematica, the following solution is obtained.

$$e^{a b}H(x-a)$$

But I don't know the solution steps.

Comment: *What* integral?

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical seems to "fail".

The $\delta$ function is not continuous, so it's a priori not differentiable. In fact, it's not even well-defined as an ordinary real-valued function, but can be made so in terms of distributions - linear maps on a space of test functions given by $f\mapsto\int\delta f=f(a)$.

It's possible to sensibly *define* derivatives of distributions by looking at representations as limits of functions:

If $\delta_i$ is a family of functions so that $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}\int\delta_i(x) f(x)\mathrm dx=f(a)$ for any test function $f$, then it can be considered a representation of the Dirac delta. Now, if we take the family of derivatives $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\delta_i$ we arrive at
$$
\int\left[\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\delta_i(x)\right]f(x)\mathrm dx=-\int\delta_i(x)\left[\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}f(x)\right]\mathrm dx
$$
through integration by parts and using the fact that $f$ has by definition compact support (which makes the boundary term vanish).

As the derivative is linear as well, this defines another linear map $f\mapsto-\int\delta f'$ on the space of test functions, which we call the derivative of our distribution.

Symbolically,
$$
\left[\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\delta(x-a)\right]f(x)=-\delta(x-a)f'(x)
$$
which you can just plug in into your formula above without any need for actual computation as it holds true by definition.

The result in this case shall be

$$e^{b x} \delta (x-a)-b e^{a b} \theta (x-a)$$

Comment: Is theta the Heaviside function ?.

Comment: @RefaatGalal Yes!

Comment: Actually, I obtain the first multiplication term in my solution as yours by using integration by parts, however, the second multiplication term doesn't include the Heaviside function. I used the rule that the integration of a function multiplied by Dirac function results into the value of the function at the function argument equal to zero.